# is it possible to display2 or more pages on another page when the links on them are clicked?

Tags: php, jquery, html

is it possible to display2 or more pages on another page when the links on them are clicked? I'm wondering if you can display two or more pages or the content of that page on another page when the link to that page I want to display is clicked.. thanks ahead.

Comment: why mark it down? im just asking.. i did all the research but found nothing that helpful relative to my question.. :(

Comment: do you know something called as popup ?

Comment: Use jQuery and AJAX to dynamically load and append the additional content

Comment: is there a function in jquery that appends the content to the same page?

Answer (score 1):

as i understand see this create a `index.php` page and set:

```
<a href="new_page.php?page=first">First Page</a>
<a href="new_page.php?page=second">Second Page</a>
```

now make a page `new_page.php` and on the above of page check like:

```
if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'first'){
   // Do anything that you want to display here
} else if( isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['second'] ){
   // Don anything that you want to dispaly here on
}
```

now see the `new_page.php` is a single page but the i check the `$_GET[]` Request
and divide that request into two different pages, as much as you want to expend this page..

Hope This help you..

Answer (score 0):

**jquery that appends the content to the same page :**

Try this :

```
<a href="javascript:show('page1.php')">First Page</a>
<a href="javascript:show('page2.php')">Second Page</a>
<div id="result"></div>

function show(page){
$('#result').html('').load(page);}
```

Comment: if I click the first link and the second link after.. will this display both of the pages i just clicked?

Comment: No, on every click div will get empty and then the page will load in it

Comment: can you help me more about this.. im really a newbie in jquery..the function

Comment: add function show(page){$('#result').html('').load(page);} inside the head tag of the page in script tag